# iOS 12 won't display .svg file as an overlay Google Maps iOS API

Tags: ios, swift

So basically I want to use an SVG file I drew as an overlay for the Google Maps iOS API 3. Whenever I use a .jpg file it seems to work fine. I'm using iOS 12

I've tried switching file names and it still only seems to work with JPEGS, not sure about PNGS.

This is my code:

```
let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 47.457925, longitude: 8.548466, zoom: 16.0)

        let southWest = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 47.444561, longitude: 8.534752)
        let northEast = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 47.483037, longitude: 8.575470)

        let overlayBounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: southWest, coordinate: northEast)

        let icon = UIImage(named: "lszh-int-lv-main.svg")

        let overlay = GMSGroundOverlay(bounds: overlayBounds, icon: icon)

        overlay.bearing = 0
        overlay.map = mapView

        mapView.camera = camera
        mapView.animate(to: camera)
```

I'm not getting any error messages with the SVG, it's just not showing up. Is it impossible to even show SVGs as overlays? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Preserve Vector Data**

> **Xcode 9** changes this situation by allowing you to choose to treat the image as a vector at runtime. This means the image can smoothly
>   scale to arbitrary sizes. The only change you need to make is to tick
>   Preserve Vector Data for the PDF image in the asset catalog.

**You need to export your vector as an pdf and add it into asset catalog.** For more info : 
[Link 1](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/creating-scaled-images-with-pdf-vectors/) [Link 2](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/xcode-9-vector-images/)